# Nanotech arms-race short story - nanodevice kills people who have read Drexler

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, nanotechnology

I think I read this short story online (and I think it was quite short) around 2000. The main character has a friend who is enthusiastic about nanotechnology and has a copy of Drexler's [*Engines of Creation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engines_of_Creation) (or possibly the more technical Drexler work [Nanosystems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471575186)); the friend believes that whoever makes the first major breakthroughs in nanotech will have an unbeatable head start.

Then copies of the book become hard to find and the friend dies or disappears. The implication is that the head start has been achieved and the person in the lead is using nanotech to find and destroy copies of Drexler's work, and detecting trace DNA of people who have read the books, so they can be killed too.  The story ends, if I recall correctly, with the protagonist realizing that he, too, is dying, because the winner in the nano-tech arms race has gotten around to people like him (known associates of nano-tech advocates).

I've checked the nanotech page at TVtropes but that doesn't list my story.

Comment: see if anything rings a bell https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Nanomachines/Literature
or here https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Nanomachines (warning, tv tropes links)

Comment: Kevin J. Anderson's "[Dogged Persistence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47316)" *F&SF*, September 1992 has woman on the run with her nano-tech enhanced dog and son from a shadowy organization known as "Purity" which aims to suppress all knowledge of nanotechnology outside of themselves, but it's not a single person, the methods are more like detective work and they use rather more direct methods.

Comment: Thanks  - a similar idea anyway